# how to download facebook message attachments in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, attachment

I success to read the facebook inbox/thread messages but i could not download the attached file from the C#

this is the attachment in Json format :

```
"attachments": {
                     "data": [
                        {
                           "id": "7c6b6bcf965711654510b4b75b91df2f",
                           "mime_type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                           "name": "CV_Test_2.docx",
                           "size": 10017
                        }
                     ]
                  }
```

i tried to use the : https://api.facebook.com/method/messaging.getattachment

using the access_token , mesage id and attachment id

but i got the error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error_response xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/">
<error_code>3</error_code>
<error_msg>Unknown method</error_msg>
<request_args list="true">
<arg>
<key>method</key>
<value>messaging.getattachment</value>
</arg>
<arg>
<key>access_token</key>
....
```

Comment: How does your C# code look like?

Comment: Hi , i'm trying to download the attachment by the url also by the web browser and i got this error #3 (above) using this url :  https://api.facebook.com/method/messaging.getattachment?access_token=[my access token]&mid=[my message id]&aid=[my attachment id]